# SQL adding number in column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a column called "Open Demand". This I´d like to show in different way => as shown in "Open Demand*".
Does anybody have any idea how to do it with SQL(oracle)?
Thanks in advance
P.

[image: Starting table]

[image: Table with a calculated column]

Comment: Please format the table first. It's unreadable right now.

Comment: And how is the value calculated?  This is not obvious.

Comment: what is your `select` statement?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: It's still not at all clear how you are arriving at these values in your new columns. Can you share the math/logic that you would use?

Comment: it‘s kind of a row calculation - there is an open demand per week (e.g. volume you should deliver), in W 15 it‘s delivered more than needed, that‘s why it‘s <0. To prevent confusions, here I‘d like to write zero, only the negative difference should be deducted from the following week (W 17 calculated like 40 - 21 = 19). As 19>0, open demands for followong week remain unchanged. Hope it will help :-)